# MapR installation on centos is erroring

Tags: hadoop, installation, mapr

I am trying to install MapR using MapR installer. I chose the disks it suggested in verification tab for each node.
The disks are `/dev/mapper/centos-pool00_tmeta` & `/dev/mapper/centos-pool00_tdata`

I can navigate to installation tab. There it shows "installing" for 20 minutes and then errors with the below message. Any help is highly appreciated.

```
2017-04-04 20:43:00.740:  failed: [fail msg="Failed to format {{ mapr.node.disks|join(',') }} for MapR-FS. Review {{ mapr_home }}/logs/disksetup.0.log, address the reported issues and retry installation"] [10.10.110.179] => {"failed": true}
Failed to format /dev/mapper/centos-pool00_tmeta,/dev/mapper/centos-pool00_tdata for MapR-FS. Review /opt/mapr/logs/disksetup.0.log, address the reported issues and retry installation
```

### disksetup.0.log

I have re run the installation and I see this error now in disk log.                                            ExitDiskSetup:210 ERROR /dev/mapper/centos-pool00_tmeta failed. Error 16, Device or resource busy. Disk is used by some other module/process.['  File "/opt/mapr/server/disksetup", line 1398, in \n    RunDiskSetup();\n', '  File "/opt/mapr/server/disksetup", line 1277, in RunDiskSetup\n    InitAllDisk(force);\n', '  File "/opt/mapr/server/disksetup", line 649, in InitAllDisk\n    disk.InitDevices(forceOption);\n', '  File "/opt/mapr/server/disksetup", line 513, in InitDevices\n    InitDisk(dev, forceOption);\n', '  File "/opt/mapr/server/disksetup", line 372, in InitDisk\n    AbortWithError(rc, errMsg, devicePath);\n', '  File "/opt/mapr/server/disksetup", line 240, in AbortWithError\n    stack_trace = traceback.format_stack(frame)\n']

Comment: What does `/opt/mapr/logs/disksetup.0.log` say?

Comment: Hi franklin , I have pasted the disksetup.0.log info in my question.

Comment: `ERROR /dev/mapper/centos-pool00_tmeta failed. Error 19, No such device`. Is the device name correct?

Comment: This is actually a link to other block    lrwxrwxrwx. 1 root root       7 Apr  3 15:01 centos-pool00_tmeta -> ../dm-0

Comment: and the disk is picked by MapR itself. I have not provided any disk name in the nodes tab. It suggested these disks in the verification tab of mapR installer

Comment: You are using standard disk. You should be using raw devices

Answer (score 0):

According to Lars' investigation, there is only one real disk - /dev/sda.  
In order to install, you need to either add a disk or create another logical volume in the Centos volume group that you tell the installer to use. 
Please see the reason for adding a disk or creating another logical volume in the Centos volume group.  Please see the full explanation `https://community.mapr.com/message/58585-mapr-installation-on-centos-is-failing`

Comment: Can you add the explanation to your answer, at least the part that directly corresponds with the question. Links can become inactive, and that way other people will be able to find your answer